# The init values did not inherited to another class with super()

Tags: python, super

I built 2 classes. first class with its own init value and another class will inherit the init values from the first class. I am wondering whether I understand it correctly of the usage of super().

```
class testing(testing_2):
    def __init__(self, name, c):
        super().__init__(name, c)

    def check(self):
        print(super().name)

class testing_2:
    def __init__(self, name, c):
        self.name = name
        self.c = c

tt = testing("tester", "check")
tt.check()
```

I thought my code was supposedly printed the "tester" because I initialize the testing class with name and c. since testing class inherit from testing_2 so we can just print the name. Am I confusing something?

My expectation is:

testing_2 will take the value from testing and we can print the values of testing_2 in testing.

Comment: You don't need to use `super` to access instance variables. You should just be able to use `self.name` in `testing`. You'll also need to define your classes the other way around.

Comment: And since `testing.__init__` isn't doing anything of its own, you can entirely omit it.

Comment: thank you so much. I was so fixated on using the method super that I messed up my knowledge. By the way, any idea of how the super() work good

Answer (score 1):

Simplify it:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, c):
        self.name = name
        self.c = c


class B(A):
    def check(self):
        print(self.name)


tt = B("tester", "check")
tt.check()
```

The `B` object will have all the same things as an `A` object, since it *inherits* them. No need to implement `__init__` on `B` if it doesn't do anything useful. You can access `self.name` directly, just as you would within `A`. The object that has that property is `self`. It's set on `self` and you can access it with `self`.

Remember, `self` is the *object instance*, not the class. When doing `B(...)`, the `self` in `A.__init__(self, ...)` is actually an instance of `B`.

You only need to explicitly use `super` if you are overriding parent methods, like in:

```
def __init__(self, name, c):
    super().__init__(name, c)
```

Here `__init__` is *overridden*, and in order to execute the parent's `__init__` you need to access it through `super`. Just `self.__init__(name, c)` would access the child's `__init__` method and you'd call it in an endless recursive loop.